# activated virtual environment doesn't work

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have virtual env called `env1`
I'm activating it via: `source env1/bin/activate`.

It does seem to be activated however if I simply run:

```
python
```

I can't import any packages I have in my virtual env. This seems to be the case with every virtual environment I have on this machine.

What's wrong with my system? or am I doing something wrong myself?

Comment: What does `which python` tell you? Is it perhaps an alias? What does `alias python` say?

Comment: You can also look at `import sys; print sys.executable` in the Python prompt to see what was started.

Comment: @MartijnPieters aye, it seems it uses non virtual env python. it uses: "/usr/bin/python". How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your `PATH` environment variable not adjusted when activating? `echo $PATH` before and after and compare.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, it seems to add the path of ve/bin at the very front of it.

Comment: Then your shell has an alias or function name or something similar that invokes the wrong interpreter, bypassing looking at `PATH`. Your virtual env `activate` script is working, but your shell configuration is interfering.

Comment: Does `declare -f python` show anything? or `alias python`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters well I've loaded a new virtual env and this time "which python" results in ve directory but still no imports.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, alias nor declare return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell just by your description but:

Activated environment will (in most linux distros) prefix your shell prompt with the name of environment. Like:

```
username@computer ~ $ source env1/bin/activate
(env1)username@computer ~ $ python
```

That should run you python from **env/bin/python**

Be sure that you have installed all packages you want included. Virtual environment can also be set to include or omit system packages. It is easily set during creation of virtualenv by including **--system-site-packages** argument.

See: http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#the-system-site-packages-option

Comment: I did in fact try running python via env/bin/python, however I still can't import any of virtual environment packages.

Comment: what is your output of **pip freeze** command when env is activated?

Comment: seems like it outputs local python packages rather than virtual env ones.

Comment: Then it looks like you don't have virtualenv activated at all.

Comment: try to install virtualenvwrapper. It really makes your life easier. http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html